# How to configure customer specific pricing in SAP Hybris through impex?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I want to show the different price for a product to different customer groups in the Hybris.
How to achieve this through Impex?

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546100/sap-hybris-how-to-display-specific-products-at-top-results-after-search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create UserPriceGroup and assign it to the price rows and customer/b2bunit

```
INSERT_UPDATE UserPriceGroup ; code[unique=true] ; name[lang=en]
                             ; group1            ; "Group 1"    
                             ; group2            ; "Group 2"  

INSERT_UPDATE PriceRow ; product(code, $catalogVersionStaged)[unique=true] ; currency(isocode)[unique=true] ; price  ; net[unique=true,default=false] ; ug(code)[allownull=true] ; unit(code)[default=pieces]
                       ; PRODUCT-1                                         ; CAD                            ; 90.00  ; false                          ; group1                   ;                           
                       ; PRODUCT-1                                         ; CAD                            ; 100.00 ; false                          ; group2                   ;                           

UPDATE Customer ; uid[unique=true] ; Europe1PriceFactory_UPG(code)
                ; cus1             ; group1                       
                ; cus2             ; group2
```

---

find the detailed [**answer here**](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/02/customer-specific-pricing-in-sap-hybris.html)